# Cannot read property 'publicRuntimeConfig' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next

I'im trying to implement `next-i18next` in my project. No fancy config right now, it's basically taking the simple sample and putting it my project at the moment. Everything seems to be fine according to the sample. But when I run `npm run dev`, I have this error

```
> npm run dev

> next-i18n@0.0.1 dev /mnt/e/Projects/next-i18n
> node server.js

/mnt/e/Projects/next-i18n/i18n.js:2
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'publicRuntimeConfig' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/e/Projects/next-i18n/i18n.js:2:60)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/mnt/e/Projects/next-i18n/server.js:5:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
```

Here is the content of `i18n.js`

```
const NextI18Next = require('next-i18next').default;
const { localeSubpaths } = require('next/config').default().publicRuntimeConfig;

const localeSubpathVariations = {
  none: {},
  foreign: {
    en: 'en'
  },
  all: {
    fr: 'fr',
    en: 'en'
  }
};

module.exports = new NextI18Next({
  otherLanguages: ['en'],
  localeSubpaths: localeSubpathVariations[localeSubpaths]
});
```

Don't really see what's missing as it is almost the same as [the one from the sample](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/blob/master/examples/simple/i18n.js)

Comment: In that same sample, there is a comment: __Do not copy paste this code__. So i would be less surprised if that code doesn't work.